# Show the error message in a popup alert rather then on status bar

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

How do I show the error message in a popup alert box similar to the image below.

[image]

*The code that I'm currently working with.*

```
BEGIN
    IF( Condition )THEN
        --Show the error as popup alert message box
        MESSAGE("This is an error.");
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you repeat the message, you'll get as a popup alert instead of getting on the status bar :

```
BEGIN
    IF( Condition )THEN
        --Show the error as popup alert message box
        MESSAGE('This is an error.');
        MESSAGE('This is an error.');
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
    END IF;
END;
```

or try as in the following way :

```
BEGIN
    IF( Condition )THEN
        --Show the error as popup alert message box
        FOR i IN 1..2
        LOOP
          MESSAGE('This is an error.');
        END LOOP;            
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
    END IF;
END;
```

or giving the second one as just an empty string( no need to repeat the same ) :

```
BEGIN
    IF( Condition )THEN
        --Show the error as popup alert message box
        MESSAGE('This is an error.');
        MESSAGE('');
        RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I am getting this error `PLS-00201: identifier 'MESSAGE' must be declared`

Comment: @YUSOFKHAN Are you sure that you internally issued the command within the `Oracle Forms` as tagged or through an IDE or command line? Eg. this is an `Oracle Forms` command, but not of `PL/SQL`. You probably need `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` provided that the `SERVEROUTPUT` option is set to `ON`.

Comment: @Okay thank you very much I was trying to use it in PL/SQL

Comment: you're welcome @YUSOFKHAN , these samples in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a5841306%20SERVEROUTPUT) might help.